# setState hook does't change state invoking from child

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am using hook in component to manage modal state.
(Class version of component reproduce the problem)
handleClick will open modal and handleModalClose should close.

I send handleModalClose to Modal component and with console.log could see, that it is processed, but the isModalOpen state not changed (the same for callback setState).
When I am trying to invoke it with setTimeout - state changes and Modal is closing.

Why the hell the state not changes when I invoke changing from child???

```
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
    // setTimeout(() => handleModalClose, 10000);
  };

  const handleModalClose = () => {
    console.log('!!!!!!!!handleModalClose');
    setModalOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      {isModalOpen && <Modal closeModal={handleModalClose} />}
    </div>
  );
```

and here is extract from Modal

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  const { closeModal } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div className="modal">
        <form className="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <button type="button" className="button_grey button_cancel_modal" onClick={closeModal}>
          </button>
```

Comment: Where are you changing isModalOpen boolean?

Comment: @AnglesvarCheenu to show or hide the modal.  Can you share the code for modal?

Comment: Does this syntax help at all: `<Modal closeModal={() => handleModalClose()} />` ? @AnglesvarCheenu He is using `useState` hook which handles the manipulation of `isModalOpen` automagically.

Comment: Try this, <Modal closeModal={() => setModalOpen(false)} />

Comment: closeModal={() => setModalOpen(false)} was is first versions. didn't help.
BTW - class version of component does same sh!t

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED.
e.stopPropagation() - added.
Modal was closed and instantly reopen by bubbling

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED. e.stopPropagation() - added.

```
  const handleModalClose = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('!!!!!!!!handleModalClose');
    setModalOpen(false);
  };
```

Modal was closed and instantly reopen by bubbling w/o this.